# Getting string from ViewModel to View in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I am trying to get a string from `ViewModel` to `View` using `PublishSubject()` but `View` is not able to get it. Following is my code in `ViewModel`:

```
var myImageURL: PublishSubject<String> = PublishSubject<String>()

self.myService.getImage(materialNo: materialNumber).subscribe(
    onNext: { [weak self] imageURL in //I am able to get url here and want to send it to View, following doesn't work
        self?.myImageURL.onNext(imageURL)
        self?.myImageURL.onCompleted()
    },
    onError: { error in },
    onCompleted: { }
)
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Code in `View`:

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

self.viewModel.myImageURL.subscribe(
    onNext: { 
        print($0 + " image url")
        self.myImageView.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: $0)!, placeholderImage:UIImage(named: "tool_placeholder"))
    },
    onError: {
        print(String(describing: $0).capitalized)
    }
)
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Although viewModel code works fine but I am not able to receive its value in `View`.

**Edit1:**
Updated code in view with drive:

```
self.viewModel.myImageURL
        .asObservable()
        .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: "Error")
        .drive(onNext: {
                        self. myImageView.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: $0)!, placeholderImage:UIImage(named: "tool_placeholder"))
                    }
            )
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: It's possible that `viewModel.myImageURL` emits a value before the view subscribes to it.  Without more context it's hard to say.  You could try putting a breakpoint in the `onNext`  block in the view model and another in the call to `subscribe` in the view and checking they happen in the expected order.  HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you subscribing the incorrect value? You defined:

```
var toolImageURL: PublishSubject<String> = PublishSubject<String>()
```

in your viewModel, but called `subscribe` on `viewModel.myImageURL`.

Comment: I had changed the name in code here, but forgot to change at declaration

Comment: @pankaj, hi. can you share the project?

Comment: No I can't as it belongs to my office

Answer (score 0):

the publish subject you're using should be 'bound' to the ImageView using a 'driver' to ensure its code it's running on the main thread (it could crash otherwise).

```
self.viewModel.myImageURL
  .asObservable()
  .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: "Error")
  .drive(self.myImageView.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: $0)!,
                               placeholderImage:UIImage(named: "tool_placeholder")))
  .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
```

Try that firstly.
Secondly, your code in the VM doesn't look that straight to me, why are you calling `onCompleted` in the `onNext` block? Why not just using the `onCompleted` block you left empty ad the bottom?

```
self.myService.getImage(materialNo: materialNumber).subscribe(
    onNext: { [weak self] imageURL in //I am able to get url here and want to send it to View, following doesn't work
        self?.myImageURL.onNext(imageURL)
        self?.myImageURL.onCompleted()
    },
    onError: { error in },
    onCompleted: { }
)
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: thanks for replying, how do I get image url in drive? Do you have any such example?

Comment: I have used your code but I am still not able to reach inside this drive block from my viewModel